# Flash/Actionscript Error 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant:_switch_antennaData

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

My compiler shows me this error:
Line 408 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant:_switch_antennaData.
Line 414 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant:_switch_antenna0Data.
Line 420 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant:_switch_antenna1Data.
Line 426 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant:_switch_antenna2Data.

I checked my as file and this is what I have:

```
407 antenna_a.subMeshes[0].material = getMaterialFromID("EXT252");
408 var _switch_antenna2Data:_switch_antenna2Data = new _switch_antenna2Data();
409 var geom_switch_antenna2:Geometry = _switch_antenna2Data.geometryData;
410 var _switch_antenna2_rd:Vector.<Number> = Vector.<Number>([1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1]);
411 var _switch_antenna2:Mesh = buildMesh(geom_switch_antenna2, _switch_antenna2_rd, "_switch_antenna2", getMaterialFromID("EXT252"), cont);

413 _switch_antenna2.subMeshes[0].material = getMaterialFromID("EXT252");
414 var _switch_antenna1Data:_switch_antenna1Data = new _switch_antenna1Data();
415 var geom_switch_antenna1:Geometry = _switch_antenna1Data.geometryData;
416 var _switch_antenna1_rd:Vector.<Number> = Vector.<Number>([1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1]);
417 var _switch_antenna1:Mesh = buildMesh(geom_switch_antenna1, _switch_antenna1_rd, "_switch_antenna1", getMaterialFromID("EXT252"), cont);

419 _switch_antenna1.subMeshes[0].material = getMaterialFromID("EXT252");
420 var _switch_antenna0Data:_switch_antenna0Data = new _switch_antenna0Data();
421 var geom_switch_antenna0:Geometry = _switch_antenna0Data.geometryData;
422 var _switch_antenna0_rd:Vector.<Number> = Vector.<Number>([1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1]);
423 var _switch_antenna0:Mesh = buildMesh(geom_switch_antenna0, _switch_antenna0_rd, "_switch_antenna0", getMaterialFromID("EXT252"), cont);

425 _switch_antenna0.subMeshes[0].material = getMaterialFromID("EXT252");
426 var _switch_antennaData:_switch_antennaData = new _switch_antennaData();
427 var geom_switch_antenna:Geometry = _switch_antennaData.geometryData;
428 var _switch_antenna_rd:Vector.<Number> = Vector.<Number>([1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1]);
429 var _switch_antenna:Mesh = buildMesh(geom_switch_antenna, _switch_antenna_rd,"_switch_antenna", getMaterialFromID("EXT252"), cont);
```

What is even a _switch_antennaData? I'm new with actionscript and Flash Professional, could somebody please help me get rid of this error?

Comment: Find out the developer of this code, and whack him hard until he'll tell you what are these types.

Comment: That's some truly fiendish code alright.

Answer (score 0):

Where is this code from? Your's or from a tutorial?

The lines that the compiler is complaining about do not make sense;

`var _switch_antenna0Data:_switch_antenna0Data = new _switch_antenna0Data();`

both the variable name and the variable type are the same, and as far as I can remember, you can't do that with AS. Regardless, thats probably not what you want.

You need to find out what type that is supposed to be, and replace accordingly across the four lines where the compiler is complaining.

After that, you are probably going to get a runtime error on lines 409, 415, 421 and 427 :)